# Why does Google Maps think traffic reduces trip time?

Tags: google-maps

More than once, Google Maps has told me it will take me 31 minutes (for example) to get to my destination, but 34 minutes (for example) without traffic.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is this a known glitch?

I realize that a moderate amount of traffic could *theoretically* speed things up, especially if the traffic is traveling in the same direction I am (by increasing the chances than an actuated traffic signal is green when I approach it), but I can't imagine Google Maps is taking that into account.